# Is it possible to have fixed width verbatimTextOutput and have texts change lines in Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have a simple app that uses `verbatimTextOutput` to display some texts. I am wondering if it is possible to have the width of `verbatimTextOutput` to be fixed and have the text output change lines?

Please see this example (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/verbatimtext_bookmark/). I also attached the code below.

As the attached screenshot shows, when the string is very long, the `verbatimTextOutput` would not show all the text. Instead, the `verbatimTextOutput` would show a scroll bar at the bottom.

[image]

However, I hope there will be no scroll bar at the bottom of the `verbatimTextOutput`. I also need that when the texts are long, change lines to fit in the `verbatimTextOutput`. Taking the following as an example, which is by clicking the bookmark button. We can see that this lengthy URL change lines, and there is no scroll bar at the bottom of the output. If the bookmark button can do that, I hope I can also make the `verbatimTextOutput` show similar characteristics and appearance of the bookmark.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

[image]

**Code**

```
library(shiny)


ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    column(
      width = 6,
      textInput(inputId = "txt", label = "Type in some texts",
                value = paste0(rep(letters, 10), collapse = "")),
      strong("Show the texts"),
      verbatimTextOutput("txt_out"),
      br(),
      bookmarkButton()
    )
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$txt_out <- renderText({
    input$txt
  })
}
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following css:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    tags$style(type='text/css', '#txt_out {white-space: pre-wrap;}'),
    column(
      width = 6,
      textInput(inputId = "txt", label = "Type in some texts",
                value = paste0(rep(letters, 10), collapse = "")),
      strong("Show the texts"),
      verbatimTextOutput("txt_out"),
      br(),
      bookmarkButton()
    )
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$txt_out <- renderText({
    input$txt
  })
}
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a follow-up question posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58524163/7669809). I would be grateful if you can take a look.

Comment: Is there a way to tweak this solution to prohibit words from being split? So that only spaces can be used to enter a new line?

Comment: Please check the different options regarding the CSS white-space property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).